# TexStudio error: cols in tabular missing

Tags: tables, texstudio

The following document end normally in TexStudio v.4.5.2 but with a red mark on `\\` command in the `tabular` environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

%% Setting questions
\newcommand{\q}[2]{#1 \textbf{\textit{[QB-#2]}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \q{A refrigerator based on ideal vapour compression cycle operates between the temperature limits of $-20^\circ$ and $40^\circ$. The refrigerant enters the condenser as saturated vapour and leaves as saturated liquid. The enthalpy and entropy values for saturated liquid and vapour at these temperature are given in the table below:}{411}
        
            \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ | c | wc{1cm} | wc{1cm} | wc{1cm} | wc{1cm} | }
                \firsthline
                Temperature & $h_f$ & $h_g$ & $S_f$ & $S_g$\\
                \hline
                $\left(^\circ C\right)$ & \multicolumn{4}{c |}{$\left(KJ/Kg\right)$}\\
                \hline
                -20 & 20 & 180 & 0.07 & 0.7366\\
                \hline
                40 & 80 & 200 & 0.3 & 0.67\\
                \lasthline
            \end{tabular}
            \end{center}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The error is like this:
[image: cols in tabular missing]

What is wrong here?

Comment: I think TeXstudio doesn't like the short version `wc{1cm}` and counts these columns twice. Try with `w{c}{1cm}` (I can't test now),

Comment: I can't reproduce the error using the provided MWE. I use TeXStudio 4.5.2 too. The result is as it should be: item above a table of five columns. So the remark above isn't the problem.

Comment: As a side note: please read the line *the condensor ass saturated vapour* .... Guess you'll notice something odd in the meaning of that line ... ;-P

Comment: Another note: you use the units kilojoule and kilogram. The correct unit symbols use a *lowercase* **k**: kJ/kg .

Comment: Off-topic: I recommend [package `siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for units. If you set them without the package, note that units should not be set italic like variables but upwards (`\mathrm`).

Comment: TexStudio didn't take it right to use `wc{1cm}` rather than `w{c}{1cm}`. So, the later solved the issue and now no error.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your table by using `tabularray` for table and `siunitx` for units, quantities  and defining `S` column type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

%% Setting questions
\newcommand{\q}[2]{#1 \textbf{\textit{[QB-#2]}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \q{A refrigerator based on ideal vapour compression cycle operates between the temperature limits of \qty{-20}{\degreeCelsius} and  \qty{40}{\degreeCelsius}. The refrigerant enters the condenser ass saturated vapour and leaves as saturated liquid. The enthalpy and entropy values for saturated liquid and vapour at these temperature are given in the table below:}{411}

            \begin{center}
            \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                         colspec = { Q[c, si={table-format=-2.0}]
                                    *{2}{Q[c, wd=1cm]} 
                                    Q[c, wd=1cm, si={table-format=1.2}]
                                    Q[c, wd=1cm, si={table-format=1.4}]},
                    cell{1}{2-Z} = {mode=math},
                        row{1,2} = {guard}
                         }

        Temperature & h_f   & h_g   & S_f   & S_g       \\
        (\si{\degreeCelsius})
                    &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    (\si{\kilo\joule\per\kilo\gram})    
                            &       &       &           \\
        -20         & 20    & 180   & 0.07  & 0.7366    \\
         40         & 80    & 200   & 0.3   & 0.67      \\
            \end{tblr}
            \end{center}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Proposed solution is independent from used LaTeX implementation (should be recent version) and editor.

Comment: I didn't know about this `siunitx` package. Thanks for your kind information. Can you please tell me why have you used `\qty` for `\degreeCelsius` and `\SI` for other units?

Comment: @Fahad, you should look in the package documentation :-). `\qty{...}{,,,}` is for wring quantities, for example in your caption `\qty{40}{\degreeCelsius}`  where     740` is value of temperature and `\degreeCelsius` unit, meanwhile `\si{....}` (observe small letters!) is for writing units only.  `SI` is old name for ˙\qty`, which were used at siunitx` version 2 (recent version is v3.2.5, last revised 2023-04-13).